# How to make latexmk use tex-live 2019 instead of tex-live 2020?

Tags: latexmk, tlmgr

I have both Tex-Live 2020 and 2019 installed (MacTeX 2020 and 2019).  Tex-Live 2020 is the default.

Once in a while I need to use tex-live 2019 instead of 2020.  For this I: i) open the Tex-Live graphical interface and switch the default distribution to 2019; ii) run (pdf)latex; and iii) switch distribution back to 2020.

Is there a way to either:

1. Make “latexmk” use Tex-Live 2019 without switching the default?
2. Switching the default from the command line?

Thanks!

Comment: for latexmk as for pdflatex you just need to switch the PATH to have the 2019 bin directory before the 2020 one.

Comment: Are you typesetting in Terminal or using a front end app?

Comment: Working on the terminal…  but @DavidCarlisle solution worked great for me.   Thanks!  I should have tried that before asking…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for latexmk as for pdflatex you just need to switch the PATH to have the 2019 bin directory before the 2020 one